# UWP Userfriendly way to check if the user has granted only camera permissions

Tags: c#, uwp, permissions

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861675/how-do-i-check-that-the-user-has-allowed-camera-access-in-a-uwp-app) question, and have tried an implementation based on it:

```
private async Task<bool> CameraPermissionCheck()
{
    MediaCapture _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    try
    {
        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private async void DoCameraStuff()
{
    bool cameraAllowed = await CameraPermissionCheck();

    if (cameraAllowed)
    {
        //DO Stuff....
    }
    else
    {
        ShowMessage("Can't Do Stuff because camera permission is denied. To grant them....");
    }
}
```

However `MediaCapture.InitializeAsync()` requires both `Webcam` and `Microphone` permissions.  Nothing I'm doing needs to capture audio, and the imaging library I'm using (ZXing) only needs `Webcam`; so this solution is less than ideal in that it requires the manifest to request user to click Yes to a permission that my application doesn't need and will never use.

Comment: As I udnerstand it, the issues is that it returns isntantly with a exception, rather then blocking until the user made it's choice?

Comment: @Christopher correct

Comment: Disclaimer: I have little experience with UWP. That said, the Documentation of InitializeAsync is very specific that it should only be called from the Primary/Original/UI Thread. "InitializeAsync will launch a consent prompt to get the user's permission for the app to access the microphone or camera. InitializeAsync should be called from the main UI thread of your app. In apps that use C# or C++, the first use of the MediaCapture object to call InitializeAsync should be on the STA thread. Calls from an MTA thread may result in undefined behavior." Are you using any form of Multithreading?

Comment: I am calling from the main/only UI thread.  Calling from elsewhere for something that needs to be UI thread only would generate a different exception.

Comment: " the InitializeAsync() check returns false immediately instead of waiting for the user to click Yes or No to the prompt. " This should not happen. This method will wait until the promote UI has value return. Show more of your code snippet, and check if lacking of `await` key word in your code.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT  I've updated my question, the check was malfunctioning because `MediaCapture` needed an additional permission (microphone) beyond what the image library I'm using (ZXing) does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Nothing I'm doing needs to capture audio, and the imaging library I'm using (ZXing) only needs Webcam;

In UWP app, if you need to use [Camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera), commonly there're two ways. One is using `MediaCapture`. As you mentioned, `MediaCapture.InitializeAsync()` requires both `webcam` and `microphone` permissions.

Another way is using [windows built-in camera UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui). You should not specify the `webcam` or `microphone` capabilities in your app manifest file if you are using `CameraCaptureUI`.This is because the Windows built-in camera app is a trusted first-party app that requires the user to initiate photo, audio, and video capture with a button press.

The library `Zxing.Net.Mobile` you are using is using the first way, `MediaCapture`. If you want to  only specify the `WebCam` capability same as the sample you linked, you need to set the [`MediaCaptureInitializationSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacaptureinitializationsettings) to video only. For example:

```
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
try
{ 
    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
    {
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video 
    });
    _isInitialized = true;
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `webcam` permission from my app and rerun it (from VS) and try to launch ZXing I don't get the camera permission prompt and ZXing goes to the same 'show a white screen instead of any video from the camera' state that I get if I request the camera in the manifest but click no to the prompt.

Comment: "I don't get the camera permission prompt" this is as expected, if you are using `CameraCaptureUI` you don't need grant permission I already mentioned in my reply. " ZXing goes to the same 'show a white screen", you need to provide your relative code spinet.. Until now you didn't provide any code snippet relative for using the camera. Check my reply again, thanks.

Comment: ZXing does need the permission to work.  Try the official UWP sample here.  It requests `webcam` permission in the manifest, if you remove the permission from the app the prompt goes away and you get whatever overlay was assigned with no camera input, which is almost a pure blank white screen in the custom overlay sub-example which is what my app's using as a template.   https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/WindowsUniversal/Sample.WindowsUniversal

Comment: @DanNeely, now I know what you want. I updated my reply to provide the new solution, this should be just what you want. Sorry to get the wrong point at first.

Comment: If your app started off originally without webcam permissions, and then you went to add them later, sometimes the consent prompt isn't ever shown.  The only way to reset the permissions to allow webcam is to go in through "App Settings" - https://www.howtogeek.com/368598/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-windows-10/